# Не получается войти в phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, apache2

Установил Apache2 и MySQL, настроил их, установил root пароль, в саму базу данных через консоль и root пароль заходит, а в phpMyAdmin никак не получается. В интернете вообще нет ответа, перепробовал всё, второй день ищу не могу найти причину

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С недавнего обновления версии MySQL задает тип пароля как "auth.socket", а по-умолчанию чтобы работал phpMyAdmin нужно "mysql_native_password", тем самым посмотрите какой у вас стоит тип командой: `SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;`
и измените его командой: `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';`

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! Помогло ааааа большое спасибо

Comment: @JohnnyMc Не за что) Советую использовать Lamp